# Не запускается окно при запуске PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Не появляется окно приложения, код из *Qt Designer*.

Пишет в консоли:

> Process finished with exit code 0

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(721, 651)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        Dialog.setFont(font)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 180, 441, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 310, 441, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 370, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;\n"
"border-radius: 50%;\n"
"color: #fff;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Registation"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Send"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(721, 651)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        Dialog.setFont(font)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 180, 441, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 310, 441, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 370, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;\n"
"border-radius: 50%;\n"
"color: #fff;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Registation"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Send"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # тут ваша логика
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @АбдулатифАбдуманнопов что не так?